The two form(include or exclude the non-negtive constraint) of KKT condition
I encountered two different forms of KKT conditions, mainly distinguished by the definition of optimization problem they correspond to:

the maximum question is defined in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and the KKT will be:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:KKT_condition}
    \text{for} \quad j = 1, \ldots ,n: \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \le \sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} \quad \text{and} = \text{if} \quad \hat{x_j} > 0
  \end{equation}
2. the maximum question is defined in $\mathbb{R}$:
the only change of KKT condition is that the "less than or equal" is shifted to "equal to"
My questions are as follows:

Are both expressions correct?
I am trying to explain the applicability of the KKT conditions (Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions) when dealing with corner solutions.In the first form, the equality holds only for non-zero components, while the components that are zero in the corner solution only need to satisfy the "less than" constraint. The second form incorporates the non-negative constraint into the constraint equation and represents the objective function through the construction of a non-negative linear combination. Is this interpretation accurate?

Thx so much!!!
